# resolve differential equation without using hypergeometric function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't resolve this differential equation
$$dx=\left(\frac{a +be^{\frac{y}{c}}}{a+b}\right)^{cd} dy,$$
where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}.$

I tried with separable variables, i.e

$$x=\int_{0}^{y}\left(\frac{a +be^{\frac{y}{c}}}{a+b}\right)^{cd} dy \\= \frac{1}{(a+b)^{cd}}\int_{0}^{y}\left(a +be^{\frac{y}{c}}\right)^{cd} dy,$$

but i can't find a solution without calling on Hypergeometric function.

Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: You technically won’t use a hypergeometric function if you can simplify your final result, which will not be a hypergeometric function then, but a special case. If you integrate, you will get something in the form of $$f(x)*\,_2F_1(a,b,b+1,z)$$ which is an [Incomplete beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/).

Answer (score 1):

Let’s find your integral of:

> $$x=  \frac{1}{(a+b)^{cd}}\int_{0}^{y}\left(a +be^{\frac{y}{c}}\right)^{cd} dy =  \frac{a^{cd}}{(a+b)^{cd}}\int_{0}^{y}\left(1 +\frac ba e^{\frac{y}{c}}\right)^{cd} dy $$

where the Incomplete Beta function is equal to:

$$\text B_z(a,b)=\int_0^z t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt,\text{Re}(a)>0$$

when we have:

$$\frac{a^{cd}}{(a+b)^{cd}}\int_{0}^{y}\left(1 +\frac ba e^{\frac{y}{c}}\right)^{cd} dy$$

let $$1 +\frac ba e^{\frac{y}{c}}=t$$ or a similar substitution and you will get that:

$$\frac{a^{cd}}{(a+b)^{cd}}\int_{0}^{y}\left(1 +\frac ba e^{\frac{y}{c}}\right)^{cd} dy= -\frac{ca^{cd}}{(a+b)^{cd}}\text B_{\left(\frac{be^{\frac zc}}{a}, \frac{b}{a}\right)}(cd+1,0) $$

where the [Generalized Incomplete Beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta4/) equals:
$$\text B_{(\alpha,\beta)}(a,b)= \int_\alpha^\beta t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt=\text B_\beta(a,b)-\text B_\alpha(a,b)$$

which is partly simplified as you can also use this formula of you do use a hypergeometric function:

> [conversion formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/)

Please correct me and give me feedback!